# On the direction of steepest ascent of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, slope

Suppose we have a plane  in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose equation is given by $$z=ax+by,$$

and let  $\textbf{n}(-a,-b,1)$ be a vector normal to this plane.

How can we intuitively explain why the projection of $\textbf{n}$ onto the $xy$-plane, $\textbf{n}'(-a,-b)$, points toward the steepest slope (with respect to a point in the $xy$-plane)?

[image]

Comment: See the first full paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1913832/265466) for a way to visualize this.

Comment: My question was partly inspired by your answer, I couldn't really understand the cylinder explanation.

Comment: For another way to visualize it, try [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1954052/265466), in which the tangent plane to a surface is intersected by a various vertical planes.

Comment: Thank you, the second answer was exactly what I was looking for.